# my laptop's fan is loud, how to make it stop?

Tags: laptop, fan, speedfan

I have cleaned my laptop many times, and there is no dust inside.  The temperatures the speedfan gives me are:

- HD0: 31 C
- TEMP1: 39 C
- CORE 0: 24 C
- CORE 1: 25 C

When the 'TEMP1' goes over 40 C it starts spinning fast and when it goes under 40 it stops spinning fast

The problem is that the temperature is always changing (from below 40 to over 40), so every few minutes the fan starts to spin loud and then stops working.  This then repeats.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Stick a pencil in it?  Note that if this is one of several models of the Sony Vaio there is a recall for the noisy fan -- they will fix it for free for 3 years after the original purchase.

Comment: Hi Dan, I forgot to mention my laptop is from toshiba(satellite a300 psaj4e) I bought it 3 years ago and unfortunately the warranty is over

Comment: It may still be worth checking the Toshiba web site.  In the Sony case they provided an "extended warranty" to cover this problem, even though the standard warranty was only a year.

Comment: Another minor point:  The Sony problem was apparently a wire that would come loose and begin to vibrate against the very thin fan case.  Some folks fixed their own systems by re-securing the wire with glue or tape.  It could be that your problem is something similar.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. Unfortunately though I've heard that toshiba doesn't offer such control over your fan but I'm not 100% sure about it. I heard that everything is hard coded in the ACPI chip and there's nothing that you can do to change it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the laptop's fan supposed to start and stop very frequently?](https://superuser.com/questions/96799/is-the-laptops-fan-supposed-to-start-and-stop-very-frequently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really varies from system to system, [speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) can probably help you if you fiddle about in the settings enough.

This is how I got my computer to behave, perhaps you can use it as a starting point for your own experimentation. (Yellow highlight where I have made changes)

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks I tried to do this, I changed all the temperatures but again it continues working like before :(

maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: speedfan can only fully Take Over the speed control if you releace any speed control that exists in the bios.

Comment: I went into bios the other day and unfortunately no such control exists. I'm not sure if this is a laptop thing in general but I remember in desktops there are no such limits. I even updated the bios and eventually my touchpad started working(well at least some good news) but nothing changed in the fan speeds.